# PDFJS in undefined when importing into a VueJS page

Tags: vue.js, pdf.js

I'm trying to import pdfjs into a VueJS page to get the title of the PDF file (and use it instead of the web viewer to render the PDF) but when I import PDFJS and output it to the console I get `undefined`.

vue file:

```
<template lang="pug">
  q-page
    iframe#pdf(:height="height" width="100%" :src="url" :class="{ 'move-up-32-px': isMobile }")
</template>

<script>
import { pdfjs } from 'pdfjs-dist/webpack'
export default {
  name: 'PDFViewer',
  data () {
    return {
      name: '',
      path: '/statics/pdfjs-2.5.207-dist/web/viewer.html',
      height: '',
      isMobile: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    url: function () {
      return this.path + '?file=' + this.name
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.name = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/' + this.$route.params.documentURL
    this.height = window.innerHeight - 82 + 'px'
    if (this.$q.platform.is.mobile) {
      this.isMobile = true
      this.height = window.innerHeight - 50 + 'px'
    }
    console.log(pdfjs) \\ undefined
  }
}
</script>
```

package.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@quasar/extras": "^1.6.0",
    "@vue/composition-api": "^0.3.4",
    "axios": "^0.18.1",
    "electron-updater": "^4.2.5",
    "quasar": "^1.9.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.8.3",
    "@quasar/app": "^1.6.0",
    "@quasar/quasar-app-extension-dotenv": "^1.0.0",
    "@quasar/quasar-app-extension-icon-genie": "^1.1.3",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "devtron": "^1.4.0",
    "electron": "^9.0.0-beta.7",
    "electron-builder": "^21.2.0",
    "electron-debug": "^3.0.1",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^2.2.4",
    "electron-packager": "^13.1.1",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.10.1",
    "eslint": "^5.10.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "pdfjs-dist": "^2.6.347",
    "pug": "^2.0.4",
    "pug-plain-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "url-loader": "^2.3.0",
    "worker-loader": "^3.0.6"
  }
```

p.s. `import { pdfjs } from 'pdfjs-dist/webpack'` and `import pdfjs from 'pdfjs-dist/webpack'` gives the same result

Answer (score 2):

try the following import

```
import * as pdfjs from 'pdfjs-dist';
```